# Running scrapy spider and progress bar simuntaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, progress-bar

I am trying to run a progress bar in my python GUI while a scrapy spider does its job. I have tried several multithreading solutions, like the one below, but none of them have worked for me.

```
p1 = Process(target=RunSpiders())
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=ProgressBar())
p2.start()
c = p1.join()
p2.join()

if c != None:
    p2.stop()
```

The `RunSpiders()` method runs two spiders, not using them directly, but creating the cmd command and executing it. The program seems to be executing only the process placed first at each time. At first I thought it was due to the fact that scrapy is an asynchronous framework, but I have more code than the one related to the cmd command execution in the `RunSpider()` method (such as prints) and those do not appear either, so I think my mistake may be caused by a bad use of `multiprocessing`.

Code for `ProgressBar()`:

```
def ProgressBar():
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=int(window_width/2), mode='indeterminate')
    progress.place(x=int(window_width/4), y=y)
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == 100:
            i = 0
        progress['value'] = i
        window.update_idletasks()
        i = i + 0.01
    print("···")
```

Code for `Runspiders():`

```
def RunSpiders():
    codeS1 = 0
    codeS2 = 0
        if s1.get():
            os.chdir('../')
            print(os.getcwd())
            cmd = "scrapy crawl Spider1"
            codeS1 = os.system(cmd)
        if s2.get():
            os.chdir('../')
            print(os.getcwd())
            cmd = "scrapy crawl Spider2"
            codeS2 = os.system(cmd)
    codeS = codeS1 + codeS2
    return codeS
```

Comment: What’s wrong with the code there? You are not showing the code that causes the progress bar to update, so if that’s the issue, your question does not seem complete enough for anyone to help.

Comment: I have added the code of both methods, hope it helps. Anyway, I think the problem is scrapy's engine, as it seems to work fine without the os.system(cmd) line

Comment: I don’t see how the progress bar is related to the code that runs the spider. Can you reproduce the issue if you take the progress bar part out of the code? If so, consider [minimizing your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), removing irrelevant code.

Comment: The progress bar is not actually related to the spider. The thing is that I want the progress bar that moves from one side to another repeatedly until the spider finishes so that the user knows the process is still running